# Set Word Document Range to Excel Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a larger project which helps generate letters in Excel based on multiple reports (on other sheets) and feeds each letter into a common Word document with page breaks inserted in between each letter. I have attempted to resolve an issue where an error was being randomly thrown stating that the clipboard was not valid. The following code produces this error on occasion:

Error-prone code:

```
Sub ExportToWordDoc(ws As Worksheet, wordDoc As Word.Document, classCount As Long)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ws.Range("A1:J" & classCount + 8).Copy
    DoEvents    'added in attempt to resolve random error
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))    'also added in attempt to resolve error
    wordDoc.Range(wordDoc.Content.End - 1).Paste    'line causes intermittent error
    wordDoc.Range(wordDoc.Content.End - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
End Sub
```

I believe that the ultimate solution will be to avoid using the clipboard for migrating the data over. Is there a way to do the following? Currently, the code below produces a type mismatch error.

```
Sub ExportToWordDoc(ws As Worksheet, wordDoc As Word.Document, classCount As Long)
    wordDoc.Range(wordDoc.Content.End - 1).Text = ws.Range("A1:J" & classCount + 8).value
    wordDoc.Range(wordDoc.Content.End - 1).InsertBreak Type:=7
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

FYI: The number of letters generated can be between 10 and 100.

Edit: Some more information.
[image: Example image of ws]

Comment: Is your Excel data a table and you are creating letters from each (or some) row(s), as in mail merge? If so, see this; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAGON0ryypo.
Else see this for reporting: https://chandoo.org/wp/2011/02/17/printing-excel-reports-via-a-word-document/

Comment: Thanks; however, I am attempting to avoid a mail merge. The data is being joined from two different sheets and the resulting user data is stored as dictionary containing user-defined class, each object of which contains various data including a collection of upcoming classes for the user. So, if done as a mail merge, I would need to have a way to pull multiple, variable items for each letter (some have 1 class, some have 10).

Comment: You don't give us enough information. What's the content of the ws.Range you're passing? What do you expect the result to be in Word? Are you trying to get a table? Then you need to insert a table and populate it, cell-by-cell. There's no way to pass a table of Excel information directly into a Word.Range.

Comment: The idea of inserting a table may be the way to go. I'll do some research, unless you have an example of how this might be implemented. Thanks @CindyMeister

Comment: Not right off-hand, no. Tip for you, though: Write the Excel data to a character-delimited string. Assign that to the Word.Range. Then use Word's Range.ConvertToTable method. Any formatting after that. Much faster / more efficient than the cell-by-cell method.

Comment: I look forward to playing with this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can find a better way in this code. This example takes the range A1:A10 on Sheet 1 and exports it to the first table in an existing Word document named "Table Report". **Note**: It doesn't use copy.

```
    Sub Export_Table_Data_Word()

        'Name of the existing Word document
        Const stWordDocument As String = "Table Report.docx"

        'Word objects.
        Dim wdApp As Word.Application
        Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim wdCell As Word.Cell

        'Excel objects
        Dim wbBook As Workbook
        Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

        'Count used in a FOR loop to fill the Word table.
        Dim lnCountItems As Long

        'Variant to hold the data to be exported.
        Dim vaData As Variant

        'Initialize the Excel objects
        Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        vaData = wsSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value

        'Instantiate Word and open the "Table Reports" document.
        Set wdApp = New Word.Application
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path &; "\" &; stWordDocument)

        lnCountItems = 1

        'Place the data from the variant into the table in the Word doc.
        For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells
            wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, 1)
            lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
        Next wdCell

        'Save and close the Word doc.
        With wdDoc
            .Save
            .Close
        End With

        wdApp.Quit

        'Null out the variables.
        Set wdCell = Nothing
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Set wdApp = Nothing

        MsgBox "The " &; stWordDocument &; "'s table has succcessfully " &; vbNewLine &; _
               "been updated!", vbInformation

    End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't had the time to apply this yet, but this is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks!